# Как я могу нарисовать линии, похожие на лучи солнца, вокруг круга?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg, css-shapes

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне в основном нужно создать этот дизайн по изображению. Я знаю, что этого можно добиться с помощью CSS, но не знаю, как это сделать. Я пробовал погуглить, но смог найти только замысловатые "солнечные" рисунки, такие как этот, что слишком много для меня, чтобы изменить мое текущее понимание.

https://codepen.io/zmmbreeze/pen/guLfC

Я создал центральную часть вот так (используя sass):

```
&__count {
    width: 12rem;
    height: 12rem;
    color: $lightPurple;
    border: $border;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 100%;
    @include centerContent;
  }
```

Как добавить "лучи"?

Вот что я пытался извлечь:

```
.count-down {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  @include centerContent;
  &__count {
    width: 12rem;
    height: 12rem;
    color: $lightPurple;
    border: $border;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 100%;
    @include centerContent;
  }

  &__go {
    width: 15rem;
    height: 15rem;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 100%;
    @include centerContent;
  }
}

.sun-light b,
.sun-light s {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12%; /* 100*30/100=18.75 */
  background: #fed65b;
}
.sun-light s {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
.sun-light:nth-child(10n + 2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(18deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(18deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(18deg);
  -ie-transform: rotate(18deg);
  transform: rotate(18deg);
}
.sun-light:nth-child(10n + 3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(36deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(36deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(36deg);
  -ie-transform: rotate(36deg);
  transform: rotate(36deg);
}
.sun-light:nth-child(10n + 4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(54deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(54deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(54deg);
  -ie-transform: rotate(54deg);
  transform: rotate(54deg);
}
.sun-light:nth-child(10n + 5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(72deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(72deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(72deg);
  -ie-transform: rotate(72deg);
  transform: rotate(72deg);
}
.sun-light:nth-child(10n + 6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ie-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.sun-light:nth-child(10n + 7) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(108deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(108deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(108deg);
  -ie-transform: rotate(108deg);
  transform: rotate(108deg);
}
.sun-light:nth-child(10n + 8) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(126deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(126deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(126deg);
  -ie-transform: rotate(126deg);
  transform: rotate(126deg);
}
.sun-light:nth-child(10n + 9) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(144deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(144deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(144deg);
  -ie-transform: rotate(144deg);
  transform: rotate(144deg);
}
.sun-light:nth-child(10n + 10) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(162deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(162deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(162deg);
  -ie-transform: rotate(162deg);
  transform: rotate(162deg);
}
```

А это мой компонент (React.js):

```
<div className="count-down">
  {timeToStart > 1 ? (
    <div className="count-down__count">{Math.floor(timeToStart)}</div>
  ) : (
    <div className="count-down__go">Go!</div>
  )}

  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
  <div class="sun-light">
    <b></b>
    <s></s>
  </div>
</div>
```

Но почему-то получаю такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How can I create "sun like" lines around a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62403621/7394871) от участника  [@Tsabary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9774624/tsabary).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62403621/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете попробовать это, используя `conic-gradient` и маску, как показано ниже.

```css
.box {
  --s:20px; /* length */
  --o:10px; /* offset */
  --w:6deg; /* thickness */
  --n:8;    /* numbers*/
  --c:green;/* color */
  
  margin:calc(var(--s) + var(--o) + 10px);
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:2px solid red;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:    calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  bottom: calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  left:   calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  right:  calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  border-radius:inherit;
  background:repeating-conic-gradient(from calc(-1*var(--w)/2), var(--c) 0 calc(var(--w) - 2deg),transparent calc(var(--w)) calc(360deg/var(--n) - 2deg),var(--c) calc(360deg/var(--n)));
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(100% - var(--s)),#fff calc(100% - var(--s)));
          mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(100% - var(--s)),#fff calc(100% - var(--s)));
}

body {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="--s:30px;--o:5px;--n:10;--c:yellow;--w:4deg"></div>
<div class="box" style="--s:15px;--o:20px;--n:6;--c:blue;--w:10deg"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для лучшей поддержки вы можете заменить конический градиент несколькими линейными градиентами, но у вас будет меньше гибкости для управления количеством лучей:

```css
.box {
  --s:20px; /* length */
  --o:10px; /* offset */
  --c:green; /* color */
  --w:4px; /* thickness*/
  
  --grad:transparent calc(50% - var(--w)/2), 
        var(--c) calc(50% - var(--w)/2 + 1px) 
                 calc(50% + var(--w)/2 - 1px), 
         transparent calc(50% + var(--w)/2);
  
  margin:calc(var(--s) + var(--o) + 10px);
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:2px solid red;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:    calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  bottom: calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  left:   calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  right:  calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  border-radius:inherit;
  background:
    /* 8 rays */
    linear-gradient(0deg   ,var(--grad)),
    linear-gradient(45deg  ,var(--grad)),
    linear-gradient(-45deg ,var(--grad)),
    linear-gradient(90deg  ,var(--grad));
    /* */
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(100% - var(--s)),#fff calc(100% - var(--s)));
          mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(100% - var(--s)),#fff calc(100% - var(--s)));
}

body {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="--s:30px;--o:5px;--c:yellow;--w:8px"></div>
<div class="box" style="--s:15px;--o:20px;--c:blue;--w:10px"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И если вы хотите учитывать радиус границы для луча, вот идея с SVG. Здесь вам нужно будет вручную настраивать SVG каждый раз, когда вы хотите иметь другой цвет, толщину или радиус:

```css
.box {
  --s:20px; /* length */
  --o:10px; /* offset */
  
  --grad:transparent calc(50% - var(--w)/2), 
        var(--c) calc(50% - var(--w)/2 + 1px) 
                 calc(50% + var(--w)/2 - 1px), 
         transparent calc(50% + var(--w)/2);
  
  margin:calc(var(--s) + var(--o) + 10px);
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:2px solid red;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:    calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  bottom: calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  left:   calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  right:  calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  border-radius:inherit;
  background:
    /* 8 rays */
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 256 256' width='256' style='transform:rotate(0deg);'> <rect x='118' y='0' width='20' height='100%' rx='10' ry='10' fill='green' /></svg>"),
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 256 256' width='256' style='transform:rotate(45deg);'> <rect x='118' y='0' width='20' height='100%' rx='10' ry='10' fill='green' /></svg>"),
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 256 256' width='256' style='transform:rotate(-45deg);'> <rect x='118' y='0' width='20' height='100%' rx='10' ry='10' fill='green' /></svg>"),
    url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 256 256' width='256' style='transform:rotate(90deg);'> <rect x='118' y='0' width='20' height='100%' rx='10' ry='10' fill='green' /></svg>");
    /* */
  background-size:100% 100%;
  -webkit-mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(100% - var(--s)),#fff calc(100% - var(--s)));
          mask:radial-gradient(farthest-side,transparent calc(100% - var(--s)),#fff calc(100% - var(--s)));
}

body {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="--s:30px;--o:5px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--s:15px;--o:20px;"></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Финальная идея без маски, SVG и сложного градиента, но с множеством элементов:

```css
.box {
  --s:20px; /* length */
  --o:10px; /* offset */
  --w:6px; /* thickness */
  --c:green;/* color */
  
  margin:calc(var(--s) + var(--o) + 10px);
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
  border:2px solid red;
  border-radius:50%;
  position:relative;
}
.box span{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:var(--w);
  left:50%;
  top:    calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  bottom: calc(-1*var(--s) - var(--o));
  border-radius:5px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c)) top,
    linear-gradient(var(--c),var(--c)) bottom;
  background-size:100% var(--s);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transform:translate(-50%) rotate(var(--r,0deg));
}

.box span:nth-child(2) { --r:45deg; }
.box span:nth-child(3) { --r:-45deg; }
.box span:nth-child(4) { --r:90deg; }

body {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>

<div class="box" style="--s:30px;--o:5px;--c:yellow;--w:4px">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>

<div class="box" style="--s:15px;--o:20px;--c:blue;--w:10px">
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62404537/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Comment: Ты как всегда в своей стихии....